# C - Bit operation without loop

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to calculate a value in function of bits in a word of variable length. Starting MSB, if bit is 1 then the value is 1/2^i. This value is multiplied by a scaling factor

Example: 110010
this would be (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/64) * scaling_factor

I have programmed it with a for loop; any idea of how this could be done avoiding the loop?

This is the code:

```
double dec_bnr (unsigned long data, int significant_bits, double scaling_factor)
{
    unsigned int temp;
    unsigned int bnr_locmask = 0x8000000;
    temp = data & bnr_locmasks[significant_bits-1];
    double result = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<significant_bits; i++){
        if((temp & bnr_locmask)==bnr_locmask){
            result+=pow (0.5, i+1);
        }
        bnr_locmask = bnr_locmask >> 1;
    }
    return result * scaling_factor;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**: Thank you for your answers; however, what I am trying to say is not what you propose. Please, let me add an example:
    data=a0280

```
A       2   4   8   16  32  64  128 256 512 1024    2048    4096    8192
1/A     0,5     0,125                               0,000488281     0,00012207
data    1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0        1        0         1   0000000

result = scaling_factor*Sum(data/A)
```

We only take into account the value 1/A if the bit for that position is 1.

Comment: What is the definition of `bnr_locmasks`?

Comment: It's a mask to leave only significant bits starting from MSB

Comment: Following the edit... data = 0xA0280 represents (1/(2^1) + 1/(2^3) + 1/(2^11) + 1/(2^13)), yes ?  If we multiply that by (2^20) we get (2^19 + 2^17 + 2^9 + 2^7), which is the integer 0xA0280... `ldexp((double)data, -20)` floats the integer 0xA0280 and then divides by (2^20)... it's not clear to me what the various respondents are missing :-(

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very easy to do without a loop:

```
double dec_bnr (unsigned long data, double scaling_factor)
{
    return data*scaling_factor/(ULONG_MAX+1.0);
}
```

It's worth noting what happens in this code.  First, `data` is converted into a `double` to match `scaling_factor` and then the numbers are multiplied, but then we do a further scaling dividing by `ULONG_MAX+1.0` which is also converted to a `double` before dividing. 
Note that

1. This can't be `ULONG_MAX + 1` because that would cause the number to remain an integer type and wrap around to zero (and thus causing a divide-by-zero error at runtime).
2. The number `ULONG_MAX + 1.0`, interpreted as a double, may well be identical to `ULONG_MAX` on 64-bit machines

It's called **fixed point arithmetic** and there are many resources available on the internet and elsewhere that explain it very well.

Comment: `ULONG_MAX` is at least 4,294,967,295. Better to use `data*scaling_factor/(ULONG_MAX+1.0)`.  There is little or nothing gained in omitting `+ 1`.

Comment: @chux: Have you tried it?  I have.  In fact, using gcc 4.8.3-1 with optimization flag `-O2` here, it generates exactly the same code either way.  There is literally nothing to be gained in including it.

Comment: Yes. `double dec_bnr (unsigned long data, double scaling_factor) { return data*scaling_factor/ULONG_MAX; } double dec_bnr1(unsigned long data, double scaling_factor) { return data*scaling_factor/(ULONG_MAX+1.0);} printf("%.20e\n", dec_bnr(1, 1.0)); printf("%.20e\n", dec_bnr1(1, 1.0));` --> "2.32830643708079737531e-10" and "2.32830643653869628906e-10" which are different answers.

Comment: Indeed... dividing by 0xFF...FF is almost bound to generate rounding, where dividing by 0x100...00 definitely won't.

Comment: ...unless the 0xFF...FF when it is floated rounds to 0x100..00 !  (As in (double)UINT64_MAX, for your usual 64-bit double.)

Comment: @chux: your program's output here is `5.42101086242752217004e-20
5.42101086242752217004e-20` which are the exact same number.

Comment: On your machine `unsigned long` is 64-bit.  In my compilation, `unsigned long` is 32-bit.  As 64-bit exceeds the significance bits of your `double`, no difference is noted.  My 32-bit did not and so a difference occurred.  `unsigned long`, by C spec, must only be at least 32-bit.

Comment: Right, and the difference between your two answers on the 32-bit machine is 5.42e-20 (very close to 0), and on my 64-bit machine exactly 0, hence my advice that "there is little difference in omitting the + 1."

Comment: Floating point numbers are logarithmically distributed and hence it is relative values that are important. `5.42e-20` is not relatively closer to `0.0` than `1.0` is to `0.0`.  If code needs absolute differences, use integers.  As you say "Technically, this should be ULONG_MAX + 1" and I agree.  There is no disadvantage to adding the 1.0 and potentially (and certainly mathematically) incorrect values result from not adding the 1.  What advantages do you see by omitting the ` + 1.0`?

Comment: Brevity and avoiding an error (using 1 instead of 1.0) were the primary advantages, but I've edited my answer to include the caveat that should address the point.

Comment: Interestingly, adding 1.0 produces the right answer if the integer is shorter than the mantissa and when it is the same length or longer -- though where the integer is exactly one bit longer than the mantissa, this is only because "round to even" saves the day -- which is very deep magic indeed !  You could do (((ULONG_MAX / 2) + 1) * 2.0), but it's a bit of a mouthful !

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `ldexp()`:

```
  double result = ldexp(data * scaling_factor, -significant_bits) ;
```

which has the advantage of expressing exactly what you are doing !  (Assuming that the `scaling_factor` is `double`.)

It also avoids any issues with constructing large powers of two (`(double)(ULONG_MAX + 1)` doesn't quite work !) and dividing, or doing `pow(2.0, -significant_bits)` and multiplying.

---

Further thought... this is, of course, equivalent:

```
  double result = ldexp((double)data, -significant_bits) * scaling_factor ;
```

But you could lump the "binary point shift" in with the `scaling_factor` (once):

```
  double scaling_factor_x = ldexp(scaling_factor, -significant_bits) ;
```

and then the conversion is simply:

```
  double result = (double)data * scaling_factor_x ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This, or something similar, should be equivalent to what you are doing:

```
(double)data / 0x100000000 * scaling_factor
```

The way binary works is that each bit has a weight twice the weight of the bit after it, so you don't need to loop through the bits like you are doing.